# Why would CSS border and background change not show up in iOS Xamarin app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a row of 4 divs that serve as buttons in my application. There is horizontal scroll allowing the buttons to maintain a certain size even on phones and smaller devices. I have jQuery code that adds a selected class to one of the buttons when it is clicked. It works in all browsers I have tested except for on my Xamarin app on my iPhone (it works in the Xamarin app on Android). On my iPhone none of the selected styles are applied when I click on the button. Do you know what could be wrong? Thanks

```js
$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  $("#btn-2").addClass("lnk-selected")
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modules {
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.lnk {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.lnk text {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.lnk-selected {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="modules">
    <div id="btn-1" class="lnk">
      <text>Button #1</text>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-2" class="lnk">
      <text>Button #2</text>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-3" class="lnk">
      <text>Button #3</text>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-4" class="lnk">
      <text>Button #4</text>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3wgydo90/3/

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: @Sean Yes I have

Comment: Have you tested Safari on your computer?

Comment: @Sean I don't have Safari on my computer. Upon further testing, I have discovered that it does work in Safari on my iPhone but does not work in the Xamarin app we have which uses the same webpage.

Comment: Can you provide some code where you reference CSS file in Xamarin application? The CSS file needs to be added to the application and referenced in the code, you can check if it is loaded correctly in the Xamarin code.